# Index on partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB container where `pk` is the partition key.

The partition key field is always a string.

What effect will the following index have?:

```json
 "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/pk/?"
        }
    ]
```

What I want to achieve is the ability search for value ranges on the partition key. But is that enabled by default, without any index definition?

Answer (score 2):

The partition key isn't indexed by default unless you used `id` as partition key since `id` is indexed by default. You'll need to define other partition keys in your indexing policy yourself if you wish to query on it without exact matches.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#includeexclude-strategy):

> The partition key property path isn't indexed by default with the exclude strategy and should be explicitly included if needed.